# How does Knockout JS process a template to produces a screen display with an icon

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js

I have inherited a project that uses knockout js. I have been trying to find a video on youtube that goes into how knockout js processes the data-bind. If anyone knows of such a video, please post it here.

What I am trying to do is add an icon to a menu pictured below.

[image]

Here is the code snippet from here:
https://github.com/openemr/openemr/blob/c6de08bad7b31204792414a93a35b98906fb36db/interface/main/tabs/menu/menus/standard.json#L3C5-L3C5

```
  {
    "icon": " fa-solid fa-calendar-days fa-2xl",
    "label": "Calendar ",
    "menu_id": "cal0",
    "target": "cal",
    "url": "/interface/main/main_info.php",
    "children": [],
    "requirement": 0,
    "acl_req": [
      "patients",
      "appt"
    ],
    "global_req_strict": [
      "!disable_calendar",
      "!ippf_specific"
    ]
  },
```

The problem is that the icon is placed outside of the div that Calendar is wrapped in.

```
<div data-bind="template: {name:header ? 'menu-header' : 'menu-action', data: $data }">
   <i data-bind="css: icon,text:helperText" class="fa closeButton fa-solid fa-calendar-days fa-2xl"></i>
   <div class="menuLabel px-1" data-bind="text:label,click: menuActionClick,css: {menuDisabled: ! enabled()}">Calendar </div>
</div>
```

To me, the data-bind is treating the icon as a separate object from the "label". Now, I would like to track down how the "black-box" knockout js is processing the template. I can find tutorials all day long that show how to consume the knockout js. What I am looking for is how to get inside the "black box".

If you can help with it understanding how knockout js process templates. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The HTML produced by Knockout looks good so far. You might want to check the css styles applied to the icon and text, in particular 'closeButton' and 'menuLabel'. It is unrelated to Knockout as far as I can see.

Comment: @Sergey thank you. That was the answer I needed. I was able to fix the display.